# What's the difference when creating a function between let x =10 and x<- return 10 in haskell

Tags: haskell

My prolog teacher asked us that and nobody could give a solid answer, and I couldn't find an answer online.

Comment: neither is an expression or syntactically-valid on its own, so you should tell the prof that the question is ill-stated

Comment: @jberryman: actually I suspect the prof stated the question rather more healthily than what the OP posted here...

Comment: He actually put the question in a test, its in Spanish but here it is its the question 3https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9cqo8b2s2ioyfa/Tarea%25201.pdf?dl=0

Comment: ...then flip your desk and storm out

Comment: Haha best advice ever

Answer (score 2):

Reading [your dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9cqo8b2s2ioyfa/Tarea%25201.pdf?dl=0), it appears that the missing context to your question is this: your professor is assuming that you're running inside GHCi, the Haskell **interpreter**, which works a bit different from the compiler.

The question, translated to English, goes like this:

> **Function definition**
>
> In Haskell functions are defined with the reserved word `let`
>
> ```
> let x = 10
> ```
>
> Another way to define a function is as follows:
>
> ```
> x <- return 10
> ```
>
> What's the difference, and what are the tradeoffs of each approach?

The first thing that's confusing the other people commenting in these questions is that neither of these is a valid expression in a Haskell source file, but both are valid **statements** in a `do` block (see leftaroundabout's answer), and because of this they're also valid input at the GHCi prompt:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Prelude> x <- return 10
Prelude> x
10

Prelude> let y = 10
Prelude> y
10
```

The second thing that's confusing is that neither of these examples is defining a function; they're binding a value to a variable.  `let` can be used to define functions, but as far as I know `<-` cannot.  It sounds to me like your teacher is mixing up the terms "function" and "variable."

In any case:

- The `let x = 10` syntax binds `x` to a *pure value*;
- The `x <- return 10` binds `x` to the *result of an action*.

So you can do the following with `variable <- action`, but not with `let variable = expression`. (Note the second line is input that I typed in.)

```
Prelude> str <- getLine
La pregunta de tu profesor me parece algo disparatada.

Prelude> str
"La pregunta de tu profesor me parece algo disparatada."
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's give both some minimial context:

```
foo, foo' :: IO ()

foo = do
   let x = 10
   print x

foo' = do
   x <- return 10
   print x
```

Both are just syntactic sugar:

```
foo ≡ (\x -> print x) 10
foo' ≡ return 10 >>= \x -> print x
```

or, if we call that common lambda `p`,

```
foo ≡ p 10
foo' ≡ return 10 >>= p
```

Clearly, `foo` is much more basic, and preferrable (in particular as it works with any return type of `p`, not just monads). However, by the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), both are actually *required* to be equivalent, for any monad!

Comment: Don't you mean that `foo` is more basic?

Comment: But let bindings are polymorphic (modulo the dreaded monomorphism restriction) and monadic bind is not.  So they are no equivalent.

Comment: @augustss: with `ImpredicativeTypes` you can make monadic binds polymorphic as well (though it requires a heck lot of extremely ugly type annotations).

Comment: ImpredicativeTypes is a crazy complex extension, whereas NoMonomorphismRestriction simplifies the type checker by removing a special case.